# Catching a delegate method call in the originating subclass

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, delegates, nsobject, uiscrollviewdelegate

I can try to explain this in terms of a UIScrollView

I'll make a subclass of UIScrollView. I want to be able to respond to its own delegate methods such as scrollViewDidScroll but at the same time let the delegate get set as normal. How can I not interfere with the delegate property, but still have the subclass be able to respond to its own delegate calls?

Comment: You can add a second delegate to your custom UIScrollView, that's trigger its owns methods.

Comment: @Larme Thanks for the input, but that is not exactly what I'm asking, sorry if I'm unclear. I want the delegate class to be able to implement all the delegate methods that UIScrollViewDelegate has to offer. But I just want to also "listen in" on a select few delegate methods, I don't want to have to implement every delegate method in the subclass just so I can foreword them to its own delegate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to subclass UIScrollView and make the delegate property private](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978279/how-to-subclass-uiscrollview-and-make-the-delegate-property-private)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will take some time but you can achieve what you want.

**//EDITED**

I have added implementation of the method `forwardInvocation:`. This method is invoked on object when object doesn't recognize message which was sent to it.

In our case when some of the `UIScrollView` delegate's methods will be called and our subclass and it doesn't implement called method, `forwardInvocation` will be called. This method checks whether called selector is part of the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol. If yes and if 'true' delegate of our class responds to this selector we forward invocation of called selector to our custom delegate.

That being said, using this solution you don't have to implement all methods of `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol in your subclass. Execution of the methods which won;t be implemented in subclass of the `ScrollView` will be forwarded to 'true' delegate of our subclass.

Example:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@protocol YourSubclassDelegate<UIScrollViewDelegate>
@end

 @interface YourSubclass ()
    @property (nonatomic, weak) id<YourSubclassDelegate> delegate;
 @end


@implementation 

//override delegate setter
- (void)setDelegate:(UIScrollViewDelegate)delegate
{
  self.customDelegate = delegate;
 [super setDelegate:self];
} 

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   //do something you want
   if ([self.customDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidScroll:)]) {
      [self.customDelegate scrollViewDidScroll:self];
   }
}


- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)selector
{
   struct objc_method_description methodDescription = protocol_getMethodDescription(@protocol(UIScrollViewDelegate), selector, YES, YES);

   if(NULL != methodDescription.name) {
      if ([self.customDelegate respondsToSelector:selector]) {
        return self.customDelegate;
      }
   }

   return nil;
 }



@end
```

Comment: This approach is good, but you can save yourself the responds to selector work by using a new protocol that extends the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol. `customDelegate` would conform to this new protocol, and would only be set in the `setDelegate` if the object conforms to the new protocol.

Comment: yea, this was my solution, I'm glad someone else thought of it too. But I was thinking there MUST be a better way.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Less code is needed to accomplish result you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you only care about `scrollViewDidScroll`, just override `layoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // your code here
}
```

`UIScrollView` sends itself `layoutSubviews` just before sending `scrollViewDidScroll:` to its delegate.

Comment: Sweet!!, I didn't think about that. This actually works for scrollViewDidScroll exactly as I needed, thanks. But It doesn't actually answer the question, so I don't think I should mark it as the answer. Sorry