# How to enable back/left swipe gesture in UINavigationController after setting leftBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I got the opposite issue from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209468/how-to-disable-back-swipe-gesture-in-uinavigationcontroller-on-ios-7).
By default in `iOS7`, back swipe gesture of `UINavigationController`'s stack could pop the presented `ViewController`. Now I just uniformed all the `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` style for all the `ViewControllers`.

Here is the code:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:LOADIMAGE(@"back_button") style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(popCurrentViewController)];
```

after that, the `navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer` is disabled. How could I make the pop gesture enabled without removing the custom `leftBarButtonItem`?

Thanks!

Comment: The same problem already have solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992039/uinavigationcontroller-interactivepopgesturerecognizer-working-abnormal-in-ios7)

Comment: @ian thanks! It means all the screen swipe gesture is for back swipe, I don't think it's a good idea.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

First set delegate in viewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

And then disable gesture when pushing:

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
    self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}
```

And enable in viewDidDisappear:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
```

Also, add `UINavigationControllerDelegate` to your view controller.

Comment: I forgot to say you should add UINavigationControllerDelegate to your view  controller.

Comment: Thanks! I just found the solution in SO just now, too! (I didn't search enough result before asking, my bad!)

Comment: Why do you set the delegate of the recognizer? You don't mention any implementation of the protocols methods?

Comment: this does not work. @hfossli's solution works perfectly. Although I tried in Swift3.

Comment: How can we make this generic and add in an existing project? We sure don't want to do this with every viewcontroller...

Comment: @AmberK Try use method

Comment: @Lumialxk did you mean reuse method? I'm thinking how will it be done without we can't implement this without overriding life cycle method or maybe having a parent view controller.. Yea thats it. thanks...

Comment: @AmberK no, I meant method swizzling. With this Objective-C feature, you can add operations before/after method implement dynamicly.

Comment: I've heard about it..but I am not sure swift has it or not..Thanks will try that.. :)

Answer (score 91):

It works for me when I set the delegate

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

and then implement

**Swift**

```
extension MyViewController:UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Can you point to any apple documentation that mentions this in relation to the 'swipe to go back' feature?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621847-interactivepopgesturerecognizer

Comment: Unfortunately this will freeze up if you swipe during a push animation or while you're on the root view controller. I posted a fix version here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43433530/308315

Comment: this works! but why? Can any one provide more explanations? Why does requiring this gesture recognizer to fail by another gesture recognizer somehow magically makes it to actually recognize the gesture??

Comment: Still saving lives! 

Answer (score 91):

You need to handle two scenarios:

1. When you're pushing a new view onto the stack
2. When you're showing the root view controller

If you just need a base class you can use, here's a Swift 3 version:

```
import UIKit

final class SwipeNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    override init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)

         delegate = self
    }
    
    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        
        delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { 
        super.init(coder: aDecoder) 

        delegate = self 
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // This needs to be in here, not in init
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }
    
    deinit {
        delegate = nil
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
    }
    
    // MARK: - Overrides
    
    override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        duringPushAnimation = true
        
        super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Private Properties
    
    fileprivate var duringPushAnimation = false

}

// MARK: - UINavigationControllerDelegate

extension SwipeNavigationController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        guard let swipeNavigationController = navigationController as? SwipeNavigationController else { return }
        
        swipeNavigationController.duringPushAnimation = false
    }
    
}

// MARK: - UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

extension SwipeNavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        guard gestureRecognizer == interactivePopGestureRecognizer else {
            return true // default value
        }
        
        // Disable pop gesture in two situations:
        // 1) when the pop animation is in progress
        // 2) when user swipes quickly a couple of times and animations don't have time to be performed
        return viewControllers.count > 1 && duringPushAnimation == false
    }
}
```

If you end up needing to act as a `UINavigationControllerDelegate` in another class, you can write a delegate forwarder [similar to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26965576/308315).

Adapted from source in Objective-C: https://github.com/fastred/AHKNavigationController

Comment: This is a great and clean solution

Comment: It does work great, thanks - but you could/should also implement the ```required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        
        delegate = self
    }``` for use with storyboards :)

Comment: I added storyboard support: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49750785/129202 Seems to work but feel free to edit it to fix any problems.

Comment: What if I don't need swipe to back for certain screens. What I need to do in that screens? I have returned false for this delegate method.  `func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {`   and set true false in viewwillAppear and disappear methods `self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled` none worked. any solutions?

Comment: How do I call this class?

Comment: @iwasrobbed, is there a way I can do something like this on a view that was presented?
Having to implement the left to right drag to dismiss the root controller.
I will really appreciate your response to this, please.

Comment: It's crashing for me on iPad '-[SwipeNavigationController pushAnimationStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10f836600'

Comment: works flawlessly to this day (iOS 16 and xcode 14.2)

Comment: What's the point of nilify the `delegate`s in the `deinit`?

Comment: Swipe back gesture is not working in map view or collection view or some other scroll view type views while using this class for navigation controller.

Answer (score 56):

it works for me **Swift 3**:

```
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

and in ViewDidLoad:

```
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
```

Comment: Also If you have a UIViewController, you should inherit from UIGestureRecognizerDelegate too.

Comment: This worked for me, but I didn't need to use the `.isEnabled` line.

Comment: Unfortunately this will freeze up if you swipe during a push animation or while you're on the root view controller. I posted a fix version here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43433530/308315

Answer (score 15):

This is the best way to enable/ disable swipe to pop view controller in ***iOS 10, Swift 3*** :

**For First Screen [ Where you want to Disable Swipe gesture ] :**

```
class SignUpViewController : UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

//MARK: - View initializers
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    swipeToPop()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func swipeToPop() {

    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true;
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self;
}

func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

    if gestureRecognizer == self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer {
        return false
    }
    return true
} }
```

**For middle screen [ Where you want to Enable Swipe gesture ] :**

```
class FriendListViewController : UIViewController {

//MARK: - View initializers
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    swipeToPop()
}

func swipeToPop() {

    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true;
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil;
} }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will freeze up if you swipe during a push animation or while you're on the root view controller. I posted a fix version here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43433530/308315

Comment: @iwasrobbed i checked the above code on root view controller and it worked fine by me i don't know why it failed on your end. Thanks for the updated version

Comment: This is perfect answer ,  
@iwasrobbed You code is not working

Comment: @NitinBhatt, cn i pls have my +1 if the answer worked for you. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

I did not need to add gestureRecognizer functions for it. It was enough for me to add following code blocks at viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: This works for me on iOS 13.3! The `delegate = nil` part was key.

Comment: Check this answer to avoid bugs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61668408/1887537

Comment: this would create a bug if the user swipe back on the first scene. recommend using this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60091707/8264784

Answer (score 11):

In Swift you can do the following code

```
import UIKit
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }
}
```

Above code helps in swift left to go back to previous controller like Facebook, Twitter.

Answer (score 10):

If you want this behaviour everywhere in your app and don't want to add anything to individual `viewDidAppear` etc. then you should create a subclass

```
class QFNavigationController:UINavigationController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
        delegate = self
    }

    override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
    }

    // IMPORTANT: without this if you attempt swipe on
    // first view controller you may be unable to push the next one
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }

}
```

Now, whenever you use `QFNavigationController` you get the desired experience.

Answer (score 8):

Swift 3:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return (otherGestureRecognizer is UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will freeze up if you swipe during a push animation or while you're on the root view controller. I posted a fix version here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43433530/308315

Answer (score 5):

I've created the following `Swift 5+` `UIViewController` extension to make it easier to add/remove the interactive pop gesture on each screen that you need it on.

Note:

- Add `enableInteractivePopGesture()` on each screen that has your custom back button
- Add `disableInteractivePopGesture()` on `viewDidAppear` for root screen of your navigation controller to prevent the swipe back issue some of the answers here mention
- Also add `disableInteractivePopGesture()` on pushed screens that you don't want to have the back button and swipe back gesture

  ```
  extension UIViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    func disableInteractivePopGesture() {
      navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
      navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
      navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
    }

    func enableInteractivePopGesture() {
      navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
      navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Setting a custom back button disable the swipe back feature.

The best thing to do to keep it is to subclass `UINavigationViewController` and set itself as the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` delegate; then you can return YES from `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` to allow the swipe back.

For example, this is done in [AHKNavigationController](https://github.com/fastred/AHKNavigationController)

And a Swift version here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43433530/308315

Comment: also pop disable when navigation bar is hidden

Answer (score 4):

Swift 5, add only these two in viewDidLoad method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43433530/129202) answer, but with storyboard support.

```
class SwipeNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    override init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

        self.setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // This needs to be in here, not in init
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    deinit {
        delegate = nil
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
    }

    // MARK: - Overrides

    override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        duringPushAnimation = true

        super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
    }

    // MARK: - Private Properties

    fileprivate var duringPushAnimation = false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having issue to enable and disable swipe interaction to pop viewcontrollers.

I have a base navigation controller and my app flow is like push Splash VC, push Main VC, and then push Some VC like that.

I want swipe to go back from Some VC to Main VC. Also disable swipe to prevent going back to splash from main VC.

After some tryings below works for me.

1. Write an extension in Main VC to disable swipe

```
extension MainViewController : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate{
    
    func disableSwipeToPop() {
        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }
    
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        
        if gestureRecognizer == self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

2. Call disableSwipeToPop() method on viewDidAppear of Main VC

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.disableSwipeToPop()
}
```

3. Write an extension in Some VC to enable swipe to pop Some VC

```
extension SomeViewController{
    
    func enableSwipeToPop() {
        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
    }
    
}
```

4. Call enableSwipeToPop() method on viewDidLoad of Some VC

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.enableSwipeToPop()
}
```

That's it. Also if you try to disable swipe on viewWillAppear, you may loose the ability to swipe again when user stops swiping to cancel the action.

Answer (score 1):

We're all working around [some old bugs](https://openradar.appspot.com/search?query=interactivePopGestureRecognizer) that haven't been fixed likely because it's "by design." I ran into the freezing problem @iwasrobbed described elsewhere when trying to nil the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer`'s delegate which seemed like it should've worked. If you want swipe behavior reconsider using `backBarButtonItem` which you *can* customize.

I also ran into `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` not working when the `UINavigationBar` is hidden. If hiding the navigation bar is a concern for you, reconsider your design before implementing a workaround for a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Most answers are pertaining to doing it on code. But I'll give you one that works on Storyboard. Yes! You read it right.

- Click on main `UINavigationController` and navigate to it's `Identity Inspector` tab.
- Under `User Defined Runtime Attributes`, set a single runtime property called `interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled` to `true`. Or graphically, you'd have to enable the checkbox as shown in the image below.

That's it. You're good to go. Your back gesture will work as if it was there all along.

[image: Image displaying the property that out to be set]

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work on Xcode 14.1

Answer (score -1):

For those who are still having trouble with this, try separating the two lines as below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.navigationController!.interactivePopGestureRecognizer!.delegate = self
    ...

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController!.interactivePopGestureRecognizer!.isEnabled = true
    ...
```

Obviously, in my app,

> interactivePopGestureRecognizer!.isEnabled

got reset to `false` before the view was shown for some reason.