# UIControllerView Back swipe stops working when setting navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

As title says. I had one controller where I was setting `interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate` to handle logic when to allow back swipe gesture and when not. It worked. But now I noticed that once I setup the delegate, the back swipe stops working. It really causes that one line of code. But why?

Yes, the controller where I used to handle the backswipe logic had everything needed (`UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol`, `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin delegate` method with return YES), but as I say, I discovered in another controller that by just calling the one line of the following code, back swipe doesn't work anymore. (Yes this another controller conforms to UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol)

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

It doesn't help if I add also:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

or

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
```

I wonder what is causing this? If I don't call that one line of code, back swipe works! And it even worked in the another controller where I handled the logic as I said.

Edit: I was setting the delegate from viewDidLoad. I tried also from viewDidAppear, but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you are setting multiple `ViewController` as the delegate. Once you set any `ViewController` as the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` delegate, that ViewController is responsible for handling the gesture and previously set any delegate will be invalid

To fix the issue you can set the delegate again when view appears in `viewWillAppear`

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Hi Mohammed. Thank you for reply. In my case, the method is called only once, and only on the second controller.

Comment: Well, in two, but i am opening only the second. If you get me, so in fact only in one. And remember, if i dont set the delegate in the controller, backswipe works. But once i set it, it doesnt work..

Comment: I think then some other code is causing the issue. I tried a sample project with the code you added and I too had that issue. I suggest you create a sample app with only navigation related code, nothing else.

Comment: I found the solution, I will post it below. Thank you for trying and help.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, if I add the following code to controller, back swipe again works. Maybe it is because i have scrollview in the controller view, but it was working before even without the following code and then it stopped. Strange. (May be i didnt have tableview on the controller where it worked, i dont remember, but i was trying it even with hidden table when it stopped working)

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942571/how-to-enable-back-left-swipe-gesture-in-uinavigationcontroller-after-setting-le).