# IOS 13 + Left Swipe is not working for previous view

Tags: ios, ios13, xcode11

I have updated to IOS 13 and now, I am not able to use left swipe to go to previous view controller in navigation controller.

Can you suggest how to solve that issue?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide more details?
Also see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942571/how-to-enable-back-left-swipe-gesture-in-uinavigationcontroller-after-setting-le

Comment: I have tried answer of above post but it is not working. I am getting that issue in IOS 13 while IOS 12, it is working

Answer (score 0):

If you struggle displaying `UINavigationController` within a modal, You can try this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return gestureRecognizer == self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer;
}
```

Comment: I think, it is due to simulator issue (iPhone 11) while it is working in iPhone 11 pro simulator.