# Hide navigation bar without losing swipe back gesture in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI, whenever the navigation bar is hidden, the swipe to go back gesture is disabled as well.

Is there any way to hide the navigation bar while preserving the swipe back gesture in SwiftUI? I've already had a custom "Back" button, but still need the gesture.

I've seen some solutions for UIKit, but still don't know how to do it in SwiftUI

Here is the code to try yourself:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
                Text("Go to second view")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View{
        Text("As you can see, swipe to go back will not work")
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or solutions are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 132, accepted):

This should work by just extending `UINavigationController`.

```swift
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }
}
```

Comment: tried your extension in simple example. and it works either with ```.navigationBarItems(leading:...``` or ```.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)```. So I think this is more elegant and simple solution

Comment: @GonzoOin from my experience it should yes.

Comment: The swipe gesture sometimes workes and sometimes the screen gets stuck when I swipe back and forth. Also I see white area while swiping back.

Comment: What should I do when my `SceneDelegate` isn't using `UINavigationController ` but `UIHostingController` as `rootViewController`?

Comment: @PKuijpers You can place this extension wherever as it will be overriding the view did load of any navigation controller used in your app.

Comment: it's work @NickBellucci. One issue there when i'm half swipe and appear detail screen again leading navigation baritem not showing

Comment: THANK YOU. I've looked for hours and your solution is the only one that worked with the exact swiping gesture. Mind explaining what does this mean: `viewControllers.count > 1`? Thank you again

Comment: @MerunasGrincalaitis that is just checking to make sure the navigation stack has more than one view controller. Essentially the gesture should return false if on the rootviewcontroller.

Comment: It works quite well except for the case when the view contains a drag gesture recognizer. I have a view that contains a Pager to switch between 2 subviews by swiping left/right (the Pager uses `highPriorityGesture`) and it doesn't work together with this code. I tried using `gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)`, but then it completely messes up the Pager. Surprisingly, the default navigation controller works with the Pager.

Comment: I had the same issues as @koleS. Any ideas on how to resolve that?

Comment: There is a bug in iOS 17 where if you swipe back to the root, using this solution, that your view will glitch out and freeze. I don't know the solution to this.

Comment: I am experiencing the same app freezes as @Andre on iOS 17, no solution as of yet.

Comment: Also experience the freeze in iOS 17 and NavigationStack

Comment: It's never a good idea to override a method in an extension. It's undefined behavior. What happens if some other code also declares an extension on the same class and it also overrides the same method?

Answer (score 29):

You need to set the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` on `UINavigationController`.

See this for a complete answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067869/1340499

My original one is shorter but introduces a bug when executing the gesture on the root.

##### Original answer

Here is the simplest working solution:

```swift
extension UINavigationController {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working great so far for me, and is simpler than Nick Bellucci's solution, so I'll make this the new accepted answer.

Comment: this one doesn't work for me in swiftui 3. The one for Nick works

Comment: @Arturo I tried this on an iOS 15-only project and it still works. Maybe other reasons?

Comment: The screen freezes for me if I'm on the root view and I swipe back. Anyone has the same issue?

Comment: yes @blrsk, I had the same issue when I used this solution. How to reproduce the issue: Navigate to a detail view, then go back to root view, and then swipe back within the root view. Then the screen will freeze.

Comment: @NguyễnKhắcHào Nick Bellucci's solution still works with the above scenario. So please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @umayanga Thanks for the steps to reproduce the issue. I tried this on iOS 15.2 and the issue still occurs. I'll revert to Nick Bellucci's answer.

Comment: Weird, this solution works for me, and I was not able to reproduce the issue following @umayanga's instructions. Perhaps because there is nothing above my root view, so there is nothing to swipe back to?

Comment: This works great, but I need to disable swiping on some of the pages. Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: Actually I need that, too. I will post a solution once I have one. 
Just googleing 'uiviewcontroller disable swipe back' does deliver some promising results already.

Comment: This solution works but how we be deactivated for certain screens?

Comment: @lopes710 you can set the pop gesture recognizer delegate on your screen and implement the delegate method that tells the system if the recognizer should act or not.

Comment: @Fab1n I can reproduce the root viewcontroller freezes - also in your case. Do you mind to share in more detail through an answer what you did which does not cause new bugs as mentioned in your last comment?

Comment: @Scorekaj22 Use the accepted answer, because it mitigates the freezing issue.

Comment: It's never a good idea to override a method in an extension. It's undefined behavior. What happens if some other code also declares an extension on the same class and it also overrides the same method?

Comment: screen freezes :/

Answer (score 12):

When using the UINavigationController extension you might encounter a bug that blocks your navigation after you start swiping the screen and let it go without navigating back. Adding `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` to NavigationView does fix this issue.

If you need different view styles based on device, this extension helps:

```
extension View {
    public func currentDeviceNavigationViewStyle() -> AnyView {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            return AnyView(self.navigationViewStyle(DefaultNavigationViewStyle()))
        } else {
            return AnyView(self.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS 16 :(

Answer (score 10):

adapting @Nick Bellucci solution but not for all screens,

> create an AppState class

```
class AppState {
    static let shared = AppState()

    var swipeEnabled = false
}
```

> add nick's extension (modified)

```
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if AppState.shared.swipeEnabled {
            return viewControllers.count > 1
        }
        return false
    }
    
}
```

> and your view

```
struct YourSwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // your code
        }
        .onAppear {
            AppState.shared.swipeEnabled = false
        }
        .onDisappear {
            AppState.shared.swipeEnabled = true
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I was looking for something like this, nice approach

Comment: It's never a good idea to override a method in an extension. It's undefined behavior. What happens if some other code also declares an extension on the same class and it also overrides the same method?

Comment: @HangarRash if that's the case you can use interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self in individual views rather than creating an extension with override method.

Answer (score 5):

Hack to hide NavigationBar globally without losing swipe back gesture in SwiftUI. It works on iOS 14 - 17.

```
import UIKit

extension UINavigationController {
    open override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        navigationBar.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution! Just a tip for others: for this extension to work, you must avoid using `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)` and `.navigationBarHidden(true)` in your custom `NavigationView` view.

Comment: Even though this is the best solution so far, I've discovered that it prevents the `SharePreview` from displaying in a `ShareLink` when used within the app.

Comment: It's never a good idea to override a method in an extension. It's undefined behavior. What happens if some other code also declares an extension on the same class and it also overrides the same method?

Comment: @HangarRash is there a method you recommend for getting this to work without extension?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple SwiftUI solution. FYI, it is not localized for right to left languages and there is no smooth animation as in the native swipe gesture.

```swift
struct SecondView: View {
  @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
  
  var body: some View{
    Text("As you can see, swipe to go back will now work without animation because of the drag gesture")
      .navigationBarTitle("")
      .navigationBarHidden(true)
      .gesture(
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 20, coordinateSpace: .global)
          .onChanged { value in // onChanged better than onEnded for this case
            guard value.startLocation.x < 20, // starting from left edge
                  value.translation.width > 60 else { // swiping right
            return
          }
        dismiss()
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution to use on iOS 17 until a fix for the native gesture is found.

Comment: I'm happy the solution is useful to at least one person. Let me know if you find a way to have the animation as well.

Comment: This is great @imthath, thank you!

For those reading, it just interrupts the native swipe back gesture with a more eager swipe gesture. 

The tab indentation is messed up but the `dismiss()` is inside the `.onChange` so it interrupts the natural flow.

I NEED this because I do not want a user to swipe back into an onboarding flow.

Answer (score 3):

I looked around documentation and other sources about this issue and found nothing. There are only a few solutions, based on using `UIKit` and `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. I tried to combine solutions [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58234142/how-to-give-back-swipe-gesture-in-swiftui-the-same-behaviour-as-in-uikit-intera) and I saved swipe back gesture even while replacing back button with other view. The code is still dirty a little, but I think that is the start point to go further (totally hide navigation bar, for example). So, here is how `ContentView` looks like:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        SwipeBackNavController {

            SwipeBackNavigationLink(destination: DetailViewWithCustomBackButton()) {
                Text("Main view")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Standard SwiftUI nav view")


        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)

    }

}

// MARK: detail view with custom back button
struct DetailViewWithCustomBackButton: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {

        Text("detail")
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                self.dismissView()
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "return")
                    Text("Back")
                }
            })
        .navigationBarTitle("Detailed view")

    }

    private func dismissView() {
        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }

}
```

Here is realization of `SwipeBackNavController` and `SwipeBackNavigationLink` which mimic `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink`. They are just wrappers for `SwipeNavigationController`'s work. The last one is a subclass of `UINavigationController`, which can be customized for your needs:

```swift
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct SwipeBackNavController<Content: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    let content: Content

    public init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> SwipeNavigationController {
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: content)
        let swipeBackNavController = SwipeNavigationController(rootViewController: hostingController)
        return swipeBackNavController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ pageViewController: SwipeNavigationController, context: Context) {

    }

}

struct SwipeBackNavigationLink<Destination: View, Label:View>: View {
    var destination: Destination
    var label: () -> Label

    public init(destination: Destination, @ViewBuilder label: @escaping () -> Label) {
        self.destination = destination
        self.label = label
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first else { return }
            guard let swipeBackNavController = window.rootViewController?.children.first as? SwipeNavigationController else { return }
            swipeBackNavController.pushSwipeBackView(DetailViewWithCustomBackButton())
        }, label: label)
    }
}

final class SwipeNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    // MARK: - Lifecycle

    override init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

        delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // This needs to be in here, not in init
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self

    }

    deinit {
        delegate = nil
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
    }

    // MARK: - Overrides

    override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        duringPushAnimation = true
        setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
    }

    var duringPushAnimation = false

    // MARK: - Custom Functions

    func pushSwipeBackView<Content>(_ content: Content) where Content: View {
        let hostingController = SwipeBackHostingController(rootView: content)
        self.delegate = hostingController
        self.pushViewController(hostingController, animated: true)
    }

}

// MARK: - UINavigationControllerDelegate

extension SwipeNavigationController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        guard let swipeNavigationController = navigationController as? SwipeNavigationController else { return }

        swipeNavigationController.duringPushAnimation = false
    }

}

// MARK: - UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

extension SwipeNavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        guard gestureRecognizer == interactivePopGestureRecognizer else {
            return true // default value
        }

        // Disable pop gesture in two situations:
        // 1) when the pop animation is in progress
        // 2) when user swipes quickly a couple of times and animations don't have time to be performed
        let result = viewControllers.count > 1 && duringPushAnimation == false
        return result
    }
}

// MARK: Hosting controller
class SwipeBackHostingController<Content: View>: UIHostingController<Content>, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        guard let swipeNavigationController = navigationController as? SwipeNavigationController else { return }
        swipeNavigationController.duringPushAnimation = false
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        guard let swipeNavigationController = navigationController as? SwipeNavigationController else { return }
        swipeNavigationController.delegate = nil
    }
}
```

This realization provides to save custom back button and swipe back gesture for now. I still don't like some moments, like how `SwipeBackNavigationLink` pushes view, so later I'll try to continue research.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! Guess I'll try this solution for now

Comment: There seems to be some problems with the extensions of ```SwipeBackNavController``` . The error message is:  "Compiling failed: extension of generic classes cannot contain '@obj' members". I tried to fix it myself but couldn't. Could you check please ?

Comment: @NguyễnKhắcHào interesting. What version of Xcode do you use?

Comment: Its 11.3.1 (11C504). Removing the extensions fixes the issue (but breaks the class).

Comment: @NguyễnKhắcHào, tomorrow I'll download new version and will try to repeat this issue. At 11.2 (11B52) it works

Comment: @NguyễnKhắcHào ok, I downloaded Xcode 11.3.1 (11C505) and ran code again - there are no errors. I actually copied code from file and paste into answer again you may try to copy it. Try to reboot or make another project - it has to work

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I’ll try to see what’s wrong with mine

Comment: Code doesn't build: `SwipeBackNavigationLink` > `body` > `swipeBackNavController .pushSwipeBackView(DetailViewWithCustomBackButton())`. This should be `(self.destination)` instead. Obvious fix, but wanted to mention nonetheless :)

Answer (score -1):

You can make navigation bar invisible. But in this case you can't handle events for part of view under navigation bar.

I use this way:

1. Set `.tint(.clear)` for `NavigationStack` for make back button "< Back" with no color. Example in my code:

```
    NavigationStack {
        ProfileView()
    }
    .tint(.clear)
    .tabItem {
        Image("profileTabImage")
            .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
        Text("")
    }
    .tag(Tab.profile)
```

2. Set `.navigationTitle("")` for remove "Back" in back button. Now you get only "<" in back button. It also need to set in previous view.
3. Set `.toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)`

Optional:
4. I use my own back button. I set image in ToolbarItem with offset, so it looks like replace default back button. Example in my code:

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
        Button {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        } label: {
            ZStack {
                Image("backProfile").offset(x: -35)
            }
        }
    }
}
```