# .Net MAUI iOS Swipe back navigation not working with regular page navigation flow

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui, .net-8.0

I'm currently using standard navigation methods instead of Shell Navigation in my application. I intended to incorporate iOS swipe back navigation, expecting it to function by default. However, it's not working as anticipated. I came across some threads discussing this issue, such as:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1143556/how-to-disable-the-swipe-back-in-ios-using-net-mau?sort=votes

I attempted to use this code on the following page to enable swipe back navigation, but unfortunately, it didn't function as intended:

So my current navigation flow goes like this:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1());
```

**From Page1:**

```
async void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
}
```

**On Page2's OnAppearing():**

```
protected override void OnAppearing()  
{  
    base.OnAppearing();  
#if IOS  
    UINavigationController vc = (UINavigationController)Platform.GetCurrentUIViewController();//using UIKit, find the UINavigationController  
    vc.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = true;  
#endif  
}
```

**Update:**
This is happening if I set the `HasNavigationBar` property of Page2 to `False`

```
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
```

Comment: Not really related to the question, but to note: many of UINavigationController things should be changed *before* UIViewController passed to UINavigationController. So, "OnAppearing" (whatever is mapped to it on Xamarin) may actually be too late

Answer (score 1):

Update:

You may try this workaround if there is no better solution.

For Page2.xaml.cs file

In OnAppearing method, make some changes to Navigationbar

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

#if IOS
    UINavigationController vc = (UINavigationController)Platform.GetCurrentUIViewController();//using UIKit, find the UINavigationController  
    vc.NavigationBar.Hidden = true;
    CoreGraphics.CGRect frame = vc.NavigationBar.Frame;
    vc.NavigationBar.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(frame.X,frame.Y - frame.Height,frame.Width,0);
#endif
}
```

In OnDisappearing method, just set it back,

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
#if IOS
    UINavigationController vc = (UINavigationController)Platform.GetCurrentUIViewController();//using UIKit, find the UINavigationController  
    vc.NavigationBar.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(barX,barY,barWidth,barHeight);
    vc.NavigationBar.Hidden = false;
#endif
}
```

In this way, the swipe back gesture will not be disabled and no space on the top of the page.

---

As @Himanshu Dwivedi said, removing NavigationBar disables the swipe back gesture.

Instead of using `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"` , use

```
#if IOS  
    UINavigationController vc = (UINavigationController)Platform.GetCurrentUIViewController();//using UIKit, find the UINavigationController  
    vc.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = true;  
    vc.NavigationBar.Hidden = true;
#endif
```

---

Swipe back is the default behavior for iOS. You don't have to set the following code in **OnAppearing** method,

```
#if IOS  
    UINavigationController vc = (UINavigationController)Platform.GetCurrentUIViewController();//using UIKit, find the UINavigationController  
    vc.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = true;  
#endif
```

But I believe that may relate to some settings for simulator or XCode. Please ensure the `Show Device Bezels` option is selected.

**Note**: If you use pair to mac, it may not work. That may due to the limitation of pair to mac. But if you use simulator on a mac, it should work.

[image]

Another way is that you could deploy it to a physical device iPhone to check if swipe back navigation works.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to test, I now understood the issue it's happening if I set the NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" of Page2's ContentPage then this swipe doesn't work.

Comment: Exactly, removing the navigation bar disables the swipe back gesture.

Comment: Is this the anticipated native behavior, or is it possible to override this behavior?

Comment: I think it's native behavior, please refer to this useful case : [Hide navigation bar without losing swipe back gesture in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921239/hide-navigation-bar-without-losing-swipe-back-gesture-in-swiftui).

Comment: I just try using  ```vc.NavigationBar.Hidden = true;``` . Seems  the gesture could be enabled.

Comment: It works after setting vc.NavigationBar.Hidden = true; but it simply hides the content of navigation bar leaving the navigation bar space empty. I have custom navigation bar in my app.

Comment: Just post a workaround. You may take a look and check if it works.