# iOS: overriding swipe gesture depending on a condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, swipe

In a `ViewController` of my iOS app I wish to override the swipe back action depending on a condition. Specifically, if a condition is met, the swipe back gesture must perform a custom action, otherwise it must perform the default action - some kind of `super` method. There are many related questions on the site, but I could not find anything related to such a `super`-like method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942571/how-to-enable-back-left-swipe-gesture-in-uinavigationcontroller-after-setting-le It seems that you can intercept the swipe back, decide and decide what to do according to your condition.

Comment: @Larme thank you, but once I intercept the gesture, how do I tell the `UIView` that it should perform the default swipe back action?

Comment: The back is a pop. So call `[self popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621886-popviewcontroller