# Swift, implement same delegate two times (without multicast)

Tags: swift, delegates

Given a very simple protocol :

```
protocol TheProtocol {
    func doSomething()
    func doSomethingElse()
    func doThis()
    func doThat()
}
```

I have a class `Base` that has a delegate waiting to be set.

```
// Can't modify this class at all
class Base  {
    public var delegate: TheProtocol?
}
```

My second class `B` inherits from this class `Base`, and implements `TheProtocol` in order to set the delegate to itself.

```
class B: Base, TheProtocol {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func doSomething() {

    }
    func doSomethingElse() {

    }
    ... other methods to implement
}
```

Now what I want to be able to do, is to have a last class `C`, that contains an instance of `B`, and also set the delegate. I want the delegate to work both inside `B` and `C`.

The major constraint is that I can't modify the `Base` class.

```
class C: TheProtocol {

    var obj = B()

    init() {
        // If I do this it won't fire within B anymore
        obj.delegate = self
    }

    func doSomething() {

    }
    func doSomethingElse() {

    }
    ... other methods to implement
}
```

Comment: Class B has to be written to proxy the delegate so it can handle the call and call the protocol method on behalf of the "real" delegate.

Comment: @RobertDresler as I mentioned, I can't modify the first class and make a multicast, it's in the title

Comment: @rmaddy, so If my protocol has 25 methods, I need to override them all, do the work, and inside call my new delegate ?

Comment: That's one way. But obviously that would be a mess with 25 methods. I suggested it because you showed 1, not 25.

Comment: @rmaddy unfortunately I did that as a simplified example. In real, I am dealing with the UICollectionViewDelegate...

Comment: That would be good information to put in your question.

Comment: I want it to be implemented two times. So B intercepts messages, but C can also have the messages.

Comment: For example, I create a class `MyCollectionView` that overrides a `UICollectionView`. In this class, I set the `delegate` to `self` so I can access `scrollViewDidScroll()`. 
But, I also want to set `MyCollectionView`'s delegate from outside:  I might want `scrollViewDidScroll()` from **outside** too. Does it make sense ? Therefore I need some proxy delegation, because I can't set the `delegate` from inside and outside.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. I can set it but obviously not make the use of two at the same time. I found some objc implementations of proxy delegate

Comment: I am trying to convert it to Swift, but not sure it'll work...
Do you have any other idea for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually possible using a Proxy delegate. However not really recommended.

[In Swift, how do I have a UIScrollView subclass that has an internal and external delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953559/in-swift-how-do-i-have-a-uiscrollview-subclass-that-has-an-internal-and-externa)